# How can I add two methods with the same name in proto file

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3

I have more than one method with the same name and different arguments in my proto and when I try to generate grpc i get an error:

> 'the method is already defined'

```
rpc method_x (Request_1) returns (response_x) {}
rpc method_x(Request_2) returns (response_x) {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The method resolution is based on *just* the name, and protobuf payloads are not self-describing so there is no way to know whether a particular payload is X vs Y - the marshaller / type is resolved from the method name.

So: no.

What you could do is use `oneof` - have one method that takes a single root message that has, as fields, one of (`oneof`) X, Y, Z, ... - essentially a discriminated union. And switch internally based on which it is after deserialization.